# MEF Import is null

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, null, mef

I have an Import that is not working - the object is null. Originally it was an ImportMany but I simplified it down to an Import to try to identify the issue but I haven't been successful in doing so.

I've gone through this site and Google and followed the main ideas:

- Don't instantiate the class yourself, let MEF do it, otherwise call container.getExport() - still doesn't work
- Put an [Export] on the class containing the [Import] property otherwise it won't be picked up as a part by the container composition process (confirmed when debugging).

My code set up is as follows (simplified for the sake of compactness):

**Assembly1**

```
public class MyBootstrapper
{
    //Automatically called by ExcelDna library, I do not instantiate this class
    public void AutoOpen()
    {
        var ac1 = new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(XLHandler).Assembly);
        var ac2 = new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(MyComponent).Assembly);

        var agc = new AggregateCatalog();
        agc.Catalogs.Add(ac1);
        agc.Catalogs.Add(ac2);

        var cc = new CompositionContainer(agc);

        try
        {
            cc.ComposeParts(this);
        }
        catch (CompositionException exception) {}
    }
}

[Export]
public class XLHandler
{
    [Import(typeof(IMyComponent))]
    public IMyComponent _component;

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        //try to use _component but it is null
    }
}
```

**Assembly2**

```
public interface IMyComponent
{
    //stuff...
}
```

**Assembly3**

```
[Export(typeof(IMyComponent)]
public MyComponent : IMyComponent
{
    //more stuff...
}
```

Anybody know/have an idea as to why the _component variable in XLHandler is not injected into by the MEF container?

Do I need to Export/create an AssemblyCatalog for the Interface in Assembly2?

Comment: Not 100% sure about this, but shouldn't the import attribute be `[Import(typeof(IMycomponent))]`?

Comment: Yes, you are exporting as `IMyComponent` so you must also import as this. You can remove the `typeof` definition from the import because your variable type is already IMyComponent.

Comment: Yup, that was a typo in the Q. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When importing parts, you can either use the `[Import]` attribute on a Property, or request it as part of the Constructor and use an `[ImportingConstructor]` attribute.

***Any part imported using the [Import] attribute will not be available in the class's constructor***

So in your case, change the `XLHandler`class like this:

```
[Export]
public class XLHandler
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public void SomeMethod(MyComponent component)
    {
        _component = component;
       // You can use _component, since it has already been resolved...
    }
}
```

Comment: Then what's the point of [Import] - sorry i'm failing to understand it. How can I inject directly into a property/class variable?

Comment: `[Import]` can be used whenever you don't need that part resolved immediately in the constructor. It will be resolved some time later, between after the constructor has finished and the time you call any property/method of that instance.

Comment: Ok, so I've changed the class variable to be a Property (added {get;set;}) but it is still null. Ideally I don't want to pass the variable as a method parameter so still baffled as to why [Import] isn't injecting the Property.

Comment: If you're trying to reference it in the constructor, it will still be null... If you want it in the Constructor (or from any method called from inside the constructor), you need to pass it as a parameter to the constructor and use `[ImportingConstructor]`

Comment: Ah ok. I'm not referring to it in the constructor - I havn't defined one. I guess because the ExcelDNA library is instantiating the class, it's possibly doing so before MEF can run the [Import]?

Comment: You're supposed to have MEF instantiate this class if you want MEF to fill the missing references... The only other option is to call the **[SatisfyImportsOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.compositioncontainer.satisfyimportsonce.aspx)** method, but you need to have a reference to the MEF container for that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25443/discussion-between-murtuza-and-blachshma)

Answer (score 2):

In `MyBootstrapper.AutoOpen` you need to replace:

```
cc.ComposeParts(this);
```

with something like:

```
var handler = new XLHandler();
cc.ComposeParts(handler);
```

or:

```
var handler = cc.GetExportedValue<XLHandler>();
```

You cannot compose the parts of `MyBootstrapper` since it has not imports. `ComposeParts` does nothing.

Another approach is to add an import to `MyBootstrapper`. Like:

```
public class MyBootstrapper
{
    [Import]
    XLHandler XLHandler;

    //Automatically called by ExcelDna library, I do not instantiate this class
    public void AutoOpen()
    {
        //Leave your implementation unchanged.
    }
}
```

By the way `MyComponent` does not compile.

Comment: Cheers. I actually used a combo of both answers but not sure how to accept both. Have upped both through.